# How to Android ListView Scrolling animation in different styles ?

Tags: android-listview, android-animation, android-library

In my Project I would like to scroll list-view animated like in MS power-point animation '
Can anyone suggest me lib for that..

I would like to display list like

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.sample

Comment: https://github.com/twotoasters/jazzylistview.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos this might be help ful for u

Comment: Thanks  Tamilselvan Kalimuthu . :D It work Great

Answer (score 0):

The DevBytes Videos of Chet Haase and Daniel Olshansky are definitly worth watching when you are thinking about ListView animation.

Start here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MIfSxgsHIs and click through the videos (on inserting, expanding, deletion animation...). Downloadable resources included, look at https://plus.google.com/explore/DevBytes for download links if not linked in the videos.