# How to show drop down effect like transition on listview in android when visible

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

> I am using listview in android. I am making it visible after fetching
>   the  data from server. I need to know how can I show drop down opening
>   effect when I make ListView Visible and closing effect also .

Answer (score 2):

> The first thing to do is to define the animations, and put them in
>   your `res/anim/` folder

**up_from_bottom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

**down_from_top.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

> Now that the animations are defined, we can implement them on our
>   ListView rows. In your ListView's adapter, add the following code:

```
 private int lastPosition = -1;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Load your view, populate it, etc...
    View view = ...;

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
    view.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I do not need Expandable list

Comment: I need a drop down effect ... as like list opens up as seen in 0.30 second of this video of youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gg1tKLQDmgw

Comment: also chk this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860256/how-to-android-listview-scrolling-animation-in-different-styles